# Formula to get sheet reference then Count instances

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I Wonder if anybody can help me with this problem I seem to have be at a stand still, I'm inside excel and have two sheets like this:

[image: Sheet1]

Which lists what Bob has done with the past 42 people who have called.

I also have another sheet which looks like this: 
[image]

Called Bobs Stats, Inside the sheet it shows and calculates(Or have manually for now) how many instances there are of these options shown above.

What I need is some formula which allows me to get the sheet where Bob's stats are stored(Bob) Which is the Colleagues name box in Cell B2 and then Count the instances of X in reason and X in destination.

I know when I do it all on one sheet I can get it to work without any problems using the sumproduct formula, but I cannot seem to get this to work across sheets hence why my demo above has been done by hand, I've seen somewhere you can reference a sheet using the Indirect function, but im not sure how this works.

I'd greatly appreciate it if anybody could assist me with this struggle I am having

Regards.

Comment: I would some how need to dynamicly reference the other sheets as the plan is to duplicate the Sheet using VBA then edit the colleague field.

Comment: Each individual Colleague has an individual sheet Just like Bob here, this is where the problem comes in, I plan on using VBA to duplicate a template sheet, which then I can modify the Colleague: B2 box and this is also going to be the sheet reference, I need to be able to get the data dynamicly from here and show it, Unless you know of a way of allowing a PivotTable to do this. Thanks for you help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting this onto `B4` in the Bob_Stats page and then drag across:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT($B$1&"!$E:$E"), "="&B$3, INDIRECT($B$1&"!$D:$D"), "="&$A4)
```

By using **INDIRECT** you can change the sheet you are refering to by changing the value in cell **B1** (currently set to Bob). So if you changed it to Mark, the formula would search for `Mark!$E:$E`.

The rest of the equations are just a complicated way of refering to the headers of the tables. You could just as easily write seperate formulas in to each cell that replaced the `"="&B$3` with `"=Store"`, `"=Sales"`, and `"=Other"`.

Hopefully that helps, let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT:**

Formula altered with reference to `http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/416975-countifs-excel-2003-a.html` for an Excel 2003 workaround.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(INDIRECT($B$1&"!$E$2:$E$43")=B$3),--(INDIRECT($B$1&"!$D$2:$D$43")=$A4))
```

Comment: This would work awesomely, if it wasn't for using Excel 2003, and CountIfs Being brought in 2007, If you have a work around for this that would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I use Excel 2010 at work so I didn't know about this problem. With a simple search I found a workaround and tried to alter my code to suit Excel 2003. Let me know if that works, or refer to the link.

Comment: Thanks once again, That's Solved my problem 90%. My only problem now is, Some of my Sheets are for Example "John F" or "Mark J" which if I enter into the B1 Colleague box presents me with a #REF! error as its unable to find the sheet due to the space I beleve, Is there any way around this or would it just be best to rename all my sheets and  go without spaces, Sorry to be a pain And thank you so much for all your help so far.

Comment: No worries! I'm not sure what your resolution was but you would just need to put the title in quotations (i.e. 'John F'). Just alter it to be `INDIRECT("'" & $B$1 & "'" & "!$E$@:$E$43)`.

Comment: It Diden't seem to show the version I created which was the same as yours, Thanks for the help once again :)